# Python dataframe zero value format

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe:

```
Col1   Col2         Col3         Col4
AAA      30   0.00000005   0.00000000
BBB       0   0.00000000   0.00000000
CCC      55   3.00554440   0.00000000

df.dtypes
Col1   object
Col2   int64
Col3   float64
Col4   float64
```

I want to re-format the `float` type column.
If the values in floats columns are "0" then set the format to integer "0". otherwise, ".6f".

```
Col1   Col2       Col3       Col4
AAA      30   0.000000          0
BBB       0          0          0
CCC      55   3.005544   0.000000
```

How can I reformat like this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
In [1692]: cols = df.select_dtypes('float').columns
In [1694]: df[cols] = np.where(df.select_dtypes('float').eq(0), 0, df.select_dtypes('float').applymap(lambda x: round(x, 6)))

In [1695]: df
Out[1695]: 
  Col1  Col2      Col3  Col4
0  AAA    30  0.000000   0.0
1  BBB     0  0.000000   0.0
2  CCC    55  3.005544   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I gather , you can make your own display function and apply the same with `df.style`

```
float_cols= df.columns[df.dtypes.values==np.dtype('float64')]
def myformat(d):
    d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(d==0,'.0f','.6f'),d.index,d.columns)
    return d1
df.style.apply(myformat,axis=None,subset=float_cols)
```

Comment: still got 0.000000

Comment: @PeterChen for which column? can you post `df.to_dict()` for the df you posted as an example to try? floats can be tricky